# Al cargar un <select> con JavaScript los datos inmediatamente desaparecen

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy tratando de cargar las *option* de un *select* al presionar un botón.

El código funciona si dichas etiquetas no están contenidas dentro de un *form*; en caso contrario, los datos se cargan pero instantáneamente vuelven a desaparecer:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        window.onload = function ()
        {
            var selectElement = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
            var boton = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];

            boton.onclick = function ()
            {       
                selectElement.innerHTML = "";

                for (var i = 1; i <= 31; ++i)
                    selectElement.innerHTML += ("<option>" + i + "</option>");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <select name="numeros"></select>
        <br/>
        <button>Cargar</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

¿A qué se debe este comportamiento?

¿Cómo puedo corregirlo?

Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: el name no es 'select' es 'numeros'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función es correcta. Lo que te está sucediendo es un error muy común y surge a causa de desconocer que un `<button>` que no tiene definido un atributo `type` por defecto es tratado como un `type="submit"`. Esto ocasiona que se lance una llamada **GET** al enviarse el formulario y como el `<form>` no tiene un atributo `action` definido se envía a la misma página donde te encuentras, provocando que se recargue y se te vuelva a quedar vacío el `<select>`

Forzando el tipo del botón para que sea `type="button"` controlarás el problema.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        window.onload = function ()
        {
            var selectElement = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
            var boton = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];

            boton.onclick = function ()
            {       
                selectElement.innerHTML = "";

                for (var i = 1; i <= 31; ++i)
                    selectElement.innerHTML += ("<option>" + i + "</option>");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <select name="numeros"></select>
        <br/>
        <button type="button">Cargar</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Como menciona @phpMyGuel, al ser un formulario, este envía un get a la misma página con los datos contenidos en el formulario, también se puede evitar agregando el atributo `onsubmit` al formulario

```html
<form onsubmit="javascript:void(0)">
</form>
```

Saludos.